# Show that any convex polygon of $n$ sides, where $n\geqslant 6$ can be divided on convex pentagons.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

> Show that any convex polygon of $n$ sides, where $n\geqslant 6$, can be divided into convex pentagons.

My work was so unefficient, the only thing that I've done was drawings of crossed polygons. I could not even divide any polygon into pentagons.  :)

Comment: Have you tried small cases? How does $n =6 $ work?

Comment: I think a would "divide" the exercise in two: 1) a convex polygon can only be divided by a segment connecting two of its points lying in different lines into other two convex polygons. 2) use some kind of induction starting with n=6, showing that any convex polygon can be divided in n-4 convex pentagons (note that you can choose n-4 points on a single side of the polygon to do this procedure). (not the vertices!).

Comment: Think of taking a polygon and cutting it with a line. The line need not pass through any vertex of the polygon, but it is allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Proof sketch, fill in the details yourself.)

Split $n = 6$ into 2 5-gons by dividing up 2 sides.
Split $n = 7$ into 2 5-gons by dividing up 1 sides.
Split $n = 8$ into 2 5-gons by connecting vertices.

For $n \geq 9$, show that we can split an $n-gon$ into a $n-4$ gon and a 5-gon by connecting vertices.

Hence we are done by (non-standard) induction.